# Can I use redirect in uiWebView to payment gateway on our website to buy codes, which we will be using for logging in iOS app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, payment-gateway

We have an iOS app and we use certain codes to login into the app and based on those get we get access to features inside app. Right now the codes are distributed physically.

But now we have to implement a feature wherein the users must be able to purchase the codes from within the app and use it.

My question is can I redirect the app to the app's website to purchase codes or implement IAP?
What is the best way it can be implemented without rejection by the Apple review?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your use case seems pretty straightforward. You will need to implement IAP. Taking payment on an external website that is accessible in any way from the app itself will lead to rejection.

Comment: Ok how can i do IAP on the server side because I have to receive code from the server once the purchase is completed @Paulw11.

Comment: Your app will need to work with your server; when the user makes a purchase, contact your server, have it validate the receipt and issue the code. Once the app has the code it can complete the purchase transaction with Apple

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality

Especially, you may be interested in following part:

> 3.1.3(a) “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or content subscriptions (specifically: magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services such as classroom management apps), provided that you agree not to directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods are not designed to discourage use of in-app purchase.
>
> 3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services: Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired elsewhere, including consumable items in multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app. You must not directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods must not discourage use of in-app purchase.

and:

> 3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

In general, it seems to be unacceptable to use UIWebView inside the app to avoid IAP, but under certain limitations you may consider redirecting a user to your website (rather in browser, than inside the app) where they will be allowed to purchase your "codes".

If I were you, I would place a "Register" button inside your app (and even block app's functionality for unregistered users) which would lead to your website and after registration I would offer buying certain codes (remaining in the web browser). Any additional "Buy codes" button inside the app may be considered as a violation of App Store review guidelines.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz great suggestion. I will try this.